# Null pointer exception with setadapter using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I want to populate a listview using array adapter however I always get null pointer exception. Here is the code of the main actvity:

```
public class ListeCategorie extends Activity {
CategorieBDD categorie;
private ArrayList<Catégorie> list = new ArrayList<Catégorie>();
private AdapterCategorie myAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_liste_categorie);
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listeoffre);
        categorie = new CategorieBDD(ListeCategorie.this);
        categorie.open();// c est pour autoriser l acces de lire de la base
        // get all produits
        list = (ArrayList<Catégorie>) categorie.getAllCategories();
        myAdapter = new AdapterCategorie(ListeCategorie.this, list);
        Log.i("testlog", list.size() + "");
        listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        myAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
        categorie.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now the adapter code

```
public class AdapterCategorie extends ArrayAdapter {
private List<Catégorie> producteur;
private LayoutInflater myinflater;
Context context;
public AdapterCategorie(Context context, ArrayList<Catégorie> data) {
    super(context, R.layout.listitem, data);
    this.context = context;
    this.producteur = data;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ConvertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
    TextView nom = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
    TextView nompro = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
    nom.setText(producteur.get(position).getNomCatégorie());

    return ConvertView;
```

and now the logcat

```
04-25 15:03:11.312: W/System.err(16710):    at com.Consultation.applicationpfe.ListeCategorie.onCreate(ListeCategorie.java:31)
04-25 15:03:11.332: W/System.err(16710):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-25 15:03:11.332: W/System.err(16710):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-25 15:03:11.332: W/System.err(16710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-25 15:03:11.332: W/System.err(16710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-25 15:03:11.332: W/System.err(16710):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
04-25 15:03:11.332: W/System.err(16710):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
04-25 15:03:11.332: W/System.err(16710):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
04-25 15:03:11.342: W/System.err(16710):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
04-25 15:03:11.362: W/System.err(16710):    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
04-25 15:03:11.362: W/System.err(16710):    at com.fiche.applicationpfe.Tabhost.onCreate(Tabhost.java:29)
04-25 15:03:11.382: W/System.err(16710):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-25 15:03:11.382: W/System.err(16710):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
```

I already tried the solution proposed in other similar posts like the setcontentview, checking if the listview is not null and checking if the list used is not empty.

Comment: which line is : `com.fiche.applicationpfe.Tabhost.onCreate(Tabhost.java:29)` ?

Comment: Does it need to extend ListActivity, not Activity? Activity won't have an adapter.

Comment: Are you sure R.id.listeoffre exists within R.layout.activity_liste_categorie and it's actually inflated? If you're getting a NullPointerException on ListView.setAdapter(Adapter), it means your reference to ListView is null, as setting a null Adapter will not throw an error, but instead remove the Adapter.

Comment: @mt0s that line is in tab widget i created since all other tabs  works fine it's not the source of the problem

Comment: @DavidChristopherReynolds It's not an obligation other lists in the application works the exact same way and it works fine

Comment: @Guardanis i am sure that it exists . I checked that again.

Comment: Try logging this before you call setAdapter: Log.d("testlog", String.valueOf(listview == null));

Comment: @Guardanis it was null the problem was that i created a listview with the same id except for one capital letter so i was calling the wrong listview all the time.Thanks for taking the time to think about a solution.

Comment: @Guardanis i made it work but somehow the listview is empty though the list already contains the information needed

Comment: Are you sure it has the info? The code you posted only shows you initializing it with new ArrayList<Categories>();

Comment: Thanks for replying I just found the problem.It was because at some point i tried to make the layout better and ended up hiding the first elments in the process.